# ACL management (file access) & security

Tags: access-control

I'll start by saying I'm not sure which stack community I'd ask my question, but I'm looking into using ACLs to manage file access on our server because of specific IT security requirements.

We mostly get by using regular Linux user/group ownership permissions since there are clear group/roles. We would like to start working with sensitive & controlled access data, which demands strict access to approved users. I was thinking of using ACLs, since single users can request access to (parts of) the same datasets other might be using.

There's enough info on how to implement ACLs, but I'm wondering how to manage them without the use of additional commercial tools - I'd like to read up on what's important, and from there implement a system that suits our needs.
I'd like to keep track of things such as which files are currently controlled by ACL, quickly add and remove access, check if all required ACLs are still in place etc. So my question is rather general, but what are other important security aspects of working with these kinds of ACLs?
Are there some other interesting reads on this subject?

Comment: Have you looked for guides or explainers of Linux ACLs already? Also, be aware that asking for recommendations of specific tools or products is out of scope for this site. We can certainly answer any _specific_ question you have about access control, though.

Comment: @CBHacking yes I've looked at how to use ACLs and how to set them. Was just wondering what were some best practice things to keep in mind of when dealing with ACLs. I know this is rather broad, but I can't ask anything specific yet, as I don't really know if there's anything more to it, or what else I'm missing...